# Get String between two strings with length 10 when you have more occurance of inbetween

Tags: c#

I want a substring of length `10` in between  `<`...`>`, e.g.

> Invoice No:< 12345sd ) <**1234567890**>

please notice, that the string can contain *many* `<` symbols and that's why a simple `IndexOf` + `Substring` is *not a solution*.

Comment: What have you tried so far?... SO [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: vote to close as too low quality a question

Comment: Give more examples because your question is unclear. What do you mean by **more of this <**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *regular expressions*:

```
  String source = "Invoice No:< 12345sd ) <1234567890>";

  // {10}    10 characters exactly 
  // {10,}   10 characters or more
  // {,10}   10 characters or few
  // {5,10}  from 5 up to 10 characters 
  var matches = Regex
    .Matches(source, @"<([^<]{10})>") 
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray(); // Or FirstOrDefault(); if you want just 1st match
```

Test

```
  // 1234567890
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", matches));
```